# Is it possible for my Clash of Clans account to be/get deleted?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I am inactive for a long time, will my Clash of Clans village ever be deleted for inactivity?
Also, is there any way to request/trigger a deletion?

Comment: This might be easy enough to answer in the one response, but your asking two questions, here. You might want to consider putting more thought into each question, and posting them separately. Removed the request for a link, as there may be alternate methods users can give to solve your problem.

Comment: @powerbuoy Yes I was not aware of the fact that SC reserves the right to remove an account if it goes inactive for longer duration. I have removed that answer of mine in account of this. But seriously though it sucks that they even have such a policy.

Answer (score 1):

No, no one can report/request a delete on your account for inactivity. Supercell will not delete your base or remove it. It will just sit and wait for the owner to eventually come back on. You also cannot delete or reset your base. The only way to get a different base would be to uninstall Clash of clans, and then reinstall and log in with a different account.